# How do I loop a statement til condition is met ?Java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, java.util.scanner, user-input

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1. Do you like computers?");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();

    if (input.equals("no")) {
        System.out.println("You should!");

    if (input.equals("yes")){
        System.out.println("I like computers too!");
```

If the user inputs anything else than "yes" or "no", how would i repeat the question til the user inputs "yes" or "no". I am new to java so detailed explanations will help.

Comment: use ``while`` and ``break``

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: If you googled `java loop`, you would immediately find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of the code nhouser9 provided (which is case-sensitive), one way to check for all variants ("Yes", "YES", "yes") is to use the .toUpperCase() method.

```
String input = "";
while (!input.toUpperCase().equals("YES") && !input.toUpperCase().equals("NO")) {
  input = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String input = "";
while (!input.equals("Yes") && !input.equals("No")) {
 input = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

The above should loop until the user has entered a valid input. Note that the input here is case sensitive - you can add more ifs to check for other cases if you need to.